# Проблема с массивом

Tags: php

Есть такой массив:

```
array(11) 
{ [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "106" [1]=> string(9) "Prod_code" [2]=> string(12) "125126515621" [3]=> string(3) "198" } 
  [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "167" [1]=> string(9) "Prod_code" [2]=> string(8) "14425dsf" [3]=> string(3) "200" } 
  [2]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "106" [1]=> string(9) "Prod_code" [2]=> string(8) "1231231c" [3]=> string(3) "199" } 
  [3]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "106" [1]=> string(9) "Prod_text" [2]=> string(8) "Товар  11" [3]=> string(3) "198" } 
  [4]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "106" [1]=> string(9) "Prod_text" [2]=> string(8) "Товар  12" [3]=> string(3) "197" } 
  [5]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "106" [1]=> string(9) "Prod_text" [2]=> string(8) "Товар  13" [3]=> string(3) "199" } 
  [6]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "106" [1]=> string(10) "Prod_price" [2]=> string(6) "100000" [3]=> string(3) "198" } 
  [7]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "106" [1]=> string(10) "Prod_price" [2]=> string(6) "105000" [3]=> string(3) "197" } 
  [8]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "106" [1]=> string(10) "Prod_price" [2]=> string(6) "110000" [3]=> string(3) "199" } 
  [9]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "167" [1]=> string(9) "Prod_text" [2]=> string(13) "123fasdsdfasd" [3]=> string(3) "200" } 
  [10]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "167" [1]=> string(10) "Prod_price" [2]=> string(3) "210" [3]=> string(3) "200" } }
```

На выходе надо получить такой результат:
Артикул: 125126515621 Товар: Товар  11 Цена: 100000
И т.д.

Comment: отформатируйте массив, print_r что-ли сделайте, и код которым вы пытались это сделать покажите.

Comment: А почему "Товар 11", а не "Товар 12"? Опять "догадайтесь, что мне надо и подскажите, как это сделать"?

Comment: Разрешают, получай.

Comment: @alexlz я разобрался что он хочет ))) и почему там Товар 11 )))

я бы сказал, что неправильный подход, формируй массив по другому...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($data as $key){
  // CODE
  echo $key['name'];
}
```

Вот и всё)

Comment: ужс, я начал разбираться, оказалось что он хочет:

1) если `$key[1] == "Prod_code"` то это артикул

2) если `$key[1] == "Prod_text"` то это Титле

3) если `$key[1] == "Prod_price"` то это Цена

4) и все они связаны по одинаковому $key[3]

Comment: Да, они связаны. Проблему решил, свормировав при выборке из бызы три массива. 1-й с  Артикулами, 2-й с Товарами, 3-й с Ценами. В 4-й записал индексы и ключи... потом цылом прошёлся по масиву и ксли есть цена и название проверяю артикул, его то можен не существовать, тогда беру нго ид и дописываю нули ... Всем спасибо, все свободны ;)